# catalog on different versions of db2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am trying to use my local `DB2 Express-C` edition to access remotely a db2 database running on a remote machine at IP `192.168.48.189`. The remote machine is running a `DB2 Workgroup Server` edition.

They are both version `v10.1`  and I am running them on LINUX.

First of all Is that possible?

When I try the following call it always returns me this error.

If I understood correctly

1. `db2tcp1` is a new node I need to create on my local to be able to connect
2. `db2inst1` is the db2 instance name of the remote db2 instance.

My local instance as well is named `db2inst1` like the remote one.

Is my command below correct?

```
db2 "CATALOG TCPIP NODE db2tcp1 REMOTE 192.168.48.189 SERVER db2inst1"

SQL0512N  A three-part name "" that references a remote object is not 
supported in the context in which it appears. Reason Code = "".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catalog remote databases in your local installation, it does not matter the db2 edition. Your command has a problem with the "server", you put the port number there. I know, that is weird.

Once you have catalooged the instance you will catalog the databases. Make sure to open the ports between two servers.

Comment: HI! I tried "db2 "CATALOG TCPIP NODE db2tcp1 REMOTE 192.168.48.189 SERVER 50000" but I have the same exact error.

Comment: p.s. when you say "open port between 2 server" should I apply some special setting to db2? I tried "telnet 192.168.48.189 50000" and I get "No route to host" error.

Comment: ..and by doing "netstat -a" on the remote box I don't see port 50000 displayed. What should I call to enable DB2 listening on port 50000?

Comment: `No route to host` indicates that you have a network connectivity issue, not a DB2 issue.

Comment: Hi Ian. I can SSH to that machine and login without any problem. Maight be something to deal exclusively with that port?